# FFmpeg commands for best quality conversion mp4 to DVD9 PAL

Tags: ffmpeg, video, dvd, conversion, video-conversion

I need to convert a mp4 H264 to DVD9 PAL with the best video quality.
I have tried to convert by WinFF, using the profile DVD PAL HQ Widescreen and the I added some commands like this:

```
-f null -target pal-dvd  -aspect 16:9 -vb 8000k -mbd rd -trellis 1 -flags +mv0 -cmp 0 -subcmp 2 -b:v 8000k  -vf "pad=0:1080:0:128,scale=720:576" -minrate 7500k -maxrate 8500k -pass 1
-f dvd -target pal-dvd  -aspect 16:9 -vb 8000k -mbd rd -trellis 1 -flags +mv0 -cmp 0 -subcmp 2 -b:v 8000k  -vf "pad=0:1080:0:128,scale=720:576" -minrate 7500k -maxrate 8500k -pass 2
```

I have tried many options: VBR two pass, single pass with the highest bitrate possible, then CBR ecc but the result disappoints me, too video noises, poor details. Differently, last month I tried VSO convertXtovideo that makes an amazing conversion but the software has too many bugs about the bitrate setting (min and max) or scaling, aspect ratio and size of files.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Most dvd players nowadays can play mp4 and mkv files if they are encoded in supported formats like h264, which you already have, if its a problem with file size, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651654/ffmpeg-how-to-split-video-efficiently)
This can help with that.

You can try using other codecs in small clips and test them on your DVD player

Comment: I need to convert the file to DVD PAL.

Comment: how old is your dvd player? im pretty sure that most autoplay dvds use h264 too.

try using setting the minrate lower and make bitrate a bit higher

Comment: hello, was your problem solved?